# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$fname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\form1.php on line 20

Tags: php, post

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Purchaser Info</title></head>

<body>

<?php include 'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname   = $_POST['fname'];
    $mid     = $_POST['mname'];
    $last    = $_POST['lname'];
    $add     = $_POST['add'];
    $mail    = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['cont'];

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($con, ("INSERT INTO tblpurchaser (fname, mi, lname, contact, email, homeadd)
            VALUES ( "$fname", "$mid", "$last", "$add", "$mail", "$contact")"));

    echo "Your record was added";

    mysqli_close($con); }?> </body>
</html>
```

Note: I'm not a good programmer.
Anyways. I've been working on this a while ago. Searched alot but I still can't find what's wrong with this. I would be grateful if someone would/could correct me. Hehehe Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace your double-quotes with single-quotes inside the VALUES section. That being said, what you're doing is extremely unsafe, as you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Provide more information on what you've done to try to solve the problem. Exactly what is the problem or the results of what you have done so far. Look at [How to ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also I would recommend learning a PHP MVC framework that has tools for accessing database securely and outputting to HTML as a view.

Comment: Yay, after I changed the double qoutes to single quotes it turns out i have a lot of error. Is there anything (more or less there is) wrong on my codes?

Comment: Im sorry for providing a little info and then ask here. Imma newbie and cant explain alot.

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
mysqli_query($con, ("INSERT INTO tblpurchaser (fname, mi, lname, contact, email, homeadd)
            VALUES ( "$fname", "$mid", "$last", "$add", "$mail", "$contact")"));
```

To

```
mysqli_query($con, ("INSERT INTO tblpurchaser (fname, mi, lname, contact, email, homeadd)
            VALUES (  "'.$fname.'",  "'.$mid.'", "'.$last.'", "'.$add.'", "'.$mail.'", "'.$contact.'")"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fname = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $mid = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['mname']);
    $last = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $add = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['add']);
    $mail = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $contact = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['cont']);

    $query = mysqli_query($con, ("INSERT INTO tblpurchaser (fname, mi, lname, contact, email, homeadd)
    VALUES ( '$fname', '$mid', '$last', '$add', '$mail', '$contact')"));

    if($query){
        echo "Your record was added";
    }
    else{
        echo  'Query Error: '.mysqli_error($con);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the text wasn't displayed when the submit button was clicked.

Comment: I moved the connection error up to see if any connection error and where is your `$con` declare?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to change include etc to $con! Sorry for that.

Comment: so i put $con above the if line and its like this
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mis");

am i correct for that?

Comment: yes its look like correct, you can have a look on http://uk1.php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: And you should use a good php editor for avoid for your general syntax error, you can use https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: It doesn't display anything yet. I hope I can find the problem soon. Haha! But yeah. Cheers for helping! :)

Comment: I modified the code a little bit, thats working for me if you try this it should work for you

Comment: Ive tried the code and it has an error that says it has an undefined index it the lname.

Comment: seems you dont have `$_POST['lname']` check your html to make sure you have the input `$_POST['lname']` or `print_r($_POST)` to check all posted data

Comment: I've refresh the page and it displayed this error.
" Query Error: Table 'mis.folder' doesn't exist "
What does it mean?

Comment: sorry it was my test table name your should be `tblpurchaser` just modified again

Comment: omg. sorry too for being dependent. haha! i didn't even noticed that.

Comment: Working but I have a problem with my db.